# CommitEditingStyle of Monotouch.Dialog RootElement

Tags: c#, iphone, monotouch.dialog

I have created my own DialogViewController class. The dialog has two levels. I want the user to be able to click an edit button that allows him to remove the elements on the second level.

Let me try to explain with some code:

```
public class TestMenu : DialogViewController
{
    public TestMenu() : base (new RootElement("Menu"), true)
    {
        Section section = new Section ();
        this.Root.Add (section);
        RootElement firstRoot = new RootElement ("First level 1");
        section.Add (firstRoot);
        RootElement secondRoot = new RootElement ("First level 2");
        section.Add (secondRoot);

        // first rootelement
        Section firstSection = new Section ();
        firstRoot.Add (firstSection);
        StringElement firstElement = new StringElement ("Second level element 1");
        firstSection.Add (firstElement);

        // Button to set edit mode
        Section buttonSection = new Section ();
        firstRoot.Add (buttonSection);
        StringElement buttonElement = new StringElement ("Edit");
        buttonElement.Tapped += delegate
        {
            // This works to get it in editing mode
            firstRoot.TableView.SetEditing(true, true);

            // This statement will not set it to editing mode
            //this.SetEditing(true, true);
        };
        buttonSection.Add (buttonElement);

        // second rootelement
        Section secondSection = new Section ();
        secondRoot.Add (secondSection);
        StringElement secondElement = new StringElement ("Second level element 2");
        secondSection.Add (secondElement);
    }

    public override Source CreateSizingSource (bool unevenRows)
    {
        return new TestSource(this);
    }

    class TestSource : DialogViewController.SizingSource 
    {

        public TestSource(DialogViewController container)
            : base (container)
        {}

        public override bool CanEditRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override void CommitEditingStyle (UITableView tableView, UITableViewCellEditingStyle editingStyle, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            // This is only fired when something is deleted in the first level
            base.CommitEditingStyle (tableView, editingStyle, indexPath);
        }
    }
}
```

When the user clicks on the Edit cell the table is set in edit mode.

Clicking on the delete icons of course does nothing. How can I enable edit mode or swipe to show the delete button on the root elements in the second level and onwards?

I have read the following post that explains how to enable the edit mode in the dialog view controller first screen: http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/Monotouch-Dialog-table-rows-not-selectable-in-edit-mode-td4658436.html

This works for the first level, but it is also possible to sublass the Source in the same way in the second level (Second level element 1)?

Comment: Can you show your code for your Source where you are enabling editing?

Comment: I have updated the code to include the Source element.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the CommitEditingStyle method to do whatever you want, rather then calling the base implementation which is what your code shows.

For example:

```
public override void CommitEditingStyle(UITableView tableView, UITableViewCellEditingStyle editingStyle, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var section = Container.Root[indexPath.Section];
    var element = section[indexPath.Row];
    section.Remove(element);
    Container.Root.Reload(section, UITableViewRowAnimation.None);
}
```

You can use those variables to manipulate if you should remove an element or not.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Unfortunately your suggestion does not work. The CommitEditingStyle method is not being called when I am on the second level. I suspect because the Source is set to the TableView on the first level. The second level has a new TableView to which I somehow have to hook up to the Source as well. I just do not know how.

Comment: Do you need to have multiple RootElements? Why not just use Sections?

Comment: Because of a vacation I could not respond sooner. I need this setup because it is a hierarchy. I could try to create a new dvc after the first level 1 is touched.